# ngOnChanges on boolean assigned to checkbox change not caught

Tags: javascript, angular, onchange

In html I have checkbox input with two way data binding:

```
<label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="mode">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
{{ mode }}
```

In component.ts I want to change route when mode will change. To do so I'm trying to listen for mode change with ngOnChanges module. My code is:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-modes',
    templateUrl: './modes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./modes.component.scss']
})

export class ModesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
    @Input() mode: boolean;
    constructor(private router: Router) { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        console.log(changes);
        this.router.navigate(['/dark']);
    }
}
```

but ngOnChanges is never executed although with interpolation I can see that mode is changing. It never console anything but it should console object.

Comment: Please post : where did you use app-modes?

Comment: What do you mean? I use is as grandgrandchild component in one of routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your code, there is no issue, except how you use `app-modes`, it should be look like this :

```
<app-modes [mode]='mode'></app-modes>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkobox-2way-binding-ngonchanges)**

Comment: Change is never executed... It doesn't console anything it's not because of async await. By the way this method doesn't return promise?

Comment: @dopeCode, please check working demo, its same as you described in your question

Comment: Why do you listen for changes in child component but not inside component where input actually lays?

Comment: because you have used `@input`, and input is for child

Comment: Can I somehow achieve so I can listen for changes in same component? I don't have any more nested component

Comment: OnChanges
 : "A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes", in our case mode is out databind of app-modes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197984/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-dopecode).